# Formula from mp3 Frame Length

Tags: mp3

I am working on an mp3 decoder, the formula to determine the length, in bytes, of an mp3 frame is

```
FrameSize = 144 * BitRate / (SampleRate + Padding)
```

I can't find anywhere that explains what the '144' represents.

Does anyone know?

Comment: I just want to note that the padding term should be outside of the denominator, both in the question and the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `144` represents total `bytes-per-frame`.

- MP3 files are generally encoded as MPEG-1 Layer 3.
- There are **1152** samples per frame in type Layer 3.
- 1152 samples / 8 bits-per-byte  = 144 bytes total.

Taking the formula for frame size (in bytes):

> FrameSize = 144 * BitRate / (SampleRate + Padding)

We can see (for MP3 with 192 bitrate @ 44.1 khz):

`144 * 192 / (44.1 + 0) = 626 bytes per audio frame` (fraction parts are ignored).