# How to corrupt mp3 files without altering general informations

Tags: python, mp3, id3, mutagen

I need to make some MP3 available on the internet for educational purpose. And I don't want it to be illegally downloaded. Thus I want to corrupt the MP3 files in such a way as to make them musically unreadable in other media players.

**Problem:**
I need to keep the metadata untouched (length, tags, etc) because I need to use `mutagen.mp3` and `mutagen.id3` on those MP3 files.

I did not try anything yet. I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long while (years) since I cared to work with MP3 bytes so double-check the frame-size numbers in my advice below. If you try something based on my guidance I can help fix any issues.

*note:* 
Use a **Hex editor** to see the inside of an MP3 and follow the bytes structure as explained below.

**Possible solution**:

If your MP3 file has metadata then it's actually **two sections** joined up... 
(*ie:* ID3 metadata + MP3 audio data).

ID3 editors only care about the **first section** so that part can be edited without affecting the audio.

The first section is **ID3** metadata which begins with 3 bytes of text "ID3" (or bytes: `49` `44` `33`). 
It will have a size (bytes length) listed in the bytes, so you can skip past the ID3 to the start of MP3.

The second section is **MP3** data which begins with 2 bytes of numbers `255` `251` (or bytes: `FF` `FB`).

The two bytes `FF FB` are the **typical** start of an MP3 frame (MP3 frame header has 4 bytes *eg:* `FF FB XX XX`). The `XX` parts will depend on the MP3 settings like its frequency, bitrate, version, etc.

To corrupt the MP3 data you could try:

- Make sure your MP3 files are encoded as **constant** bitrate or **CBR**, (not **Variable** bitrate, or **VBR**).
  This makes it easier to locate the start of each MP3 frame. Every frame will have a matching `FF FB XX XX` signature. They will all be the same size so, once you know bytes length from checking first frame, you can skip by that same number to reach next (or any) MP3 frame's start (*eg:* you can use **multiply** to reach a specific frame number).
- To find an MP3 frame's bytes length: See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123251/2057709) to a similar Question.
  The formula is `FrameSize = 144 * BitRate / (SampleRate + Padding)` (CBR = zero padding).
  *example : (bitrate=192, sampleRate=44.1 khz)* 
   `144 * 192 / (44.1 + 0) = 626 bytes per audio frame`.
- **Replace** every `FF FB` at each frame's start with random bytes like `AA AA` or even `AB CD` ... If no longer the expected `FF FB` then an MP3 player should refuse to play it, giving an error like: "Invalid MP3 file".
- Later your own app can always put back (replace) the current 2 bytes with the expected `FF FB` and then do audio playback. You do this **un-corruption** by skipping past ID3 bytes to get to the first frame's position and replace the found first two bytes as `FF FB`.

Comment: Hint: `0xFF 0xFB` indeed works for MPEG-1 Audio Layer III only. Restricting this method to CBR doesn't make sense, because VBR frames can be calculated, too. Also the formula does not account for potential CRC bytes in frames to forward to your next `0xFF 0xFB` sequence.

Comment: **(1)** Yes `0xFF 0xFB` because a lower audio quality is not expected from Asker who sells online courses. **(2)** CBR makes sense if the Asker is a beginner at bytes modification. When they understand the concept with easy one CBR number then they can do 30+ calculations per sec for VBR (if they like VBR encoding & its related media player issues). **(3)** CRC is not accounted for because it has nothing to do with concept of corrupting MP3 frame header. Once concept (and MP3 specs) is understood then asker can write (or hire for) their own solid MP3 encryption/corruption.

Answer (score 1):

You could record your own "music" (a whisper or clapping hands) and create your own mp3. Or you could use some royality free snippet from Wikipedia.