# Framesize and calculation in mp3

Tags: mp3

I read this post not so long ago : [Formula from mp3 Frame Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103676/formula-from-mp3-frame-length)

And I was wondering about the answer, because the author of the answer said that 144 bytes represents the total bytes-per-frame, but later the framesize was bigger than 144 bytes per frame it was now 626 bytes per frame (audio frame).

I'm a bit puzzled, doesn't 1152 samples/ 8 bits-per-byte mean the minimum size 1 sample take to storage ? Like 1 sample takes 8 bits minimum to storage and bitrate can changes this size (make it bigger), so that 1 sample can take more place than 8 bits ? But 8 bits is a minimum I though so the word "total bytes-per-frame" is correct ?