# How to find frame length of stereo mp3

Tags: python-3.x, mp3, voice, decoder

[Related question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103676/formula-from-mp3-frame-length)

Here

```
FrameSize = 144 * BitRate / (SampleRate + Padding)
```

gives the frame length. So is it the same for stereo data ?
I have a mp3 file with bit rate 128kbps, sample rate constant 44100 Hz and is stereo.

Using the above formula I tried to read mp3 as
`open(file_path, 'rb')`

`frame_data = mp3_file.read(int(frame_size))`

then, only first time I get proper header, then not!
So I think the above formula is for mono data.
How to get the frame length for stereo file?

Answer (score 0):

The bitrate is the bitrate regardless of the channel count.  MP3 takes advantage of the fact that most content between the left and right channels is going to be the same, and only encodes the differences.  (Unless of course there is discrete channel encoding happening, but that is super rare and almost always a bug in the encoding software or its configuration.)

Comment: thank you for the clarification. But one more interesting thing I noticed; 11111111111110111001000001100100 is the fame header.First two frames have same header then it changed, 11111111111110111001001001100100. That is most of the frames have padding, i.e padding bit is 1, and some do not. why is that? The file is constant bit rate so that shouldn't be all frames of same length? here non padded are 417 bytes and padded are 418 bytes frames.

Comment: @jpambattu It's a lossy codec... trying to get an exact bitrate is hard, so the padding is used to get it there.